# Android app not requesting for permission (Kotlin, jetpack compose)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-permissions

I am trying to request for `Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT` but the app doesn't ask for it.

`MainActivity.kt`

```kotlin
@Composable
fun DeviceCapsule(navController: NavHostController, name: String = "", macAddress: String = "") {
    ...

    val launcher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
        ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()
    ) { isGranted: Boolean ->
        if (isGranted) {
            // Permission Accepted: Do something
            Log.d(ABC_TAG,"PERMISSION GRANTED")
        } else {
            // Permission Denied: Do something
            Log.d(ABC_TAG,"PERMISSION DENIED")
        }
    }

...

Button(
        onClick = {
                // Check permission
                when (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                        context,
                        Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
                    ) -> {
                        navController.navigate(Routes.ChatPage.createRoute(macAddress))
                        // Some works that require permission
                        Log.d(ABC_TAG, "Code requires permission")
                    }
                    else -> {
                        // Asking for permission
                        launcher.launch(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT)
                    }
                }
            }
     )
```

`AndroidManifest.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"
        android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"
        android:maxSdkVersion="30" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN"
        android:usesPermissionFlags="neverForLocation" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth" android:required="true"/>

...
```

Comment: Have you declared the permission in your manifest file?

Comment: Yes I have. Let me edit the question